# How to ignore opening quote in views sort

Tags: views, 8

I use views to display a sorted list of book titles. Titles that begin with a quote are listed first. I want to ignore the quote for sorting purposes. So, instead of:

- "Once Upon a Time": Fairy Tales in Reality
- Grimm's Fairy Tales
- The Best Book of Fairy Tales

I want:

- Grimm's Fairy Tales
- "Once Upon a Time": Fairy Tales in Reality
- The Best Book of Fairy Tales

It appears the Views Natural Sort module will handle this, but it's still in Alpha for Drupal 8. Is there another, relatively straightforward (non-custom-code if possible) means of accomplishing this?

I've read a number of posts addressing more complex situations with fairly complex solutions, but it seems something this simple should have a simple solution.

Comment: Views Natural Sort seems to be that simple solution you're looking for. Where did you get stuck configuring it? If there were a simpler solution then wouldn't that module use it?

Comment: Thanks @prkos. I shied away from it because it's still alpha. I read the documentation and it looked like it was somewhat complex. But I'll go ahead and give it a try and then report back here how it works for me.

Comment: @prkos By way of report, Views Natural Sort seems to work pretty well, except I haven't been able to get it to ignore curly quotes at the beginning of a title. I'll work on that some more and report again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the suggestions. After I got Natural Sort mostly working, I ran into problems using the sorted titles with Views grouping due to accented letters (no fault of Natural Sort). For example, I'd get a group with "A" as the group heading and another group with "Á" (accented A).

To solve this problem, I did the following:

- Add a field named `sort_title` to the content type and hide it from users.
- Add a `node_presave()` hook for the content type to a custom module.
- Create a `sortable_title` function in the hook to

  - Replace accented letters and other international characters in the title with close English equivalents.
  - Force the entire title to uppercase.
  - Strip all non-alphanumeric characters from the front of the title.
  - Add a ~ character to titles that begin with a number (because I want them to sort after titles beginning with letters).
- Save this sortable title in the `sortable_title` field for the node.
- Use the `sortable_title` field for sorting and grouping in the view, instead of the regular title field, which I was using (and which is still the one that gets displayed).
- I also subthemed the views-view-list.html.twig template to replace the ~ with # in the grouped heading (I had already subthemed the file for another reason anyway).

This approach isn't the most general, but it's giving me exactly the outcome I want, so I'm no longer using Natural Sort. It's only about 30 lines of code in the hook function (most of that being a table of international characters and their replacements) and of course, there's the hidden duplicate of the title field.

Answer (score 1):

[views_natural_sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_natural_sort) is able to do this kind of sorting.

It might be currently in alpha state but it already has more than 250 installation for the alpha 3 release which means that  most major bugs should have already been ironed out.

Upon enabling you are able to choose title to sort with and you are given 2 extra options for natural sorting (`sort natually ascending` and `sort natually descending`)

[image]

It also has some handy settings at `admin/structure/views/settings/views_natural_sort` which you will allow you to chose what other characters you want to ignore (and other settings)

Following are the default settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, @GiorgosK. I set up Natural Sort and used the settings you mention. Even after that, I wasn't able to get quite what I needed because of the international characters in the titles I'm sorting. I'll post an answer to explain what I ended up doing.Maybe that will prompt you or someone to say, "Natural Sort could have done that as well" or to make another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wouldn't recommend views_natural_sort module for solving described issue.
Especially when you have lots of content (I have 200K nodes). views_natural_sort creates a dedicated table and store there cleaned up fields.
For my case it sounds overkill.

I used next approach:

- installed and enable [views_sort_expression](https://dgo.to/views_natural_sort)
- added "Expression" sort criteria into the view
- configured "Expression".

Expression:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(node_field_data.title, '^Panelblock: +|^Panel: +|[«»"()„] ?|(  )', '')
```

Which replaces specific chars, interested words and double spaces.

And then views generates such query:

```
SELECT 
  ..., 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(node_field_data.title, '^Panelblock: +|^Panel: +|[«»"()„] ?|(  )', '') AS "views_sort_expression_0"
FROM
  {node_field_data} "node_field_data"
WHERE 
  ...
ORDER BY
  ...
  "views_sort_expression_0" ASC
LIMIT ...
```

Tip: to build and test regex use awesome https://regex101.com/ service.